# Невозможно копирование из виджета text в Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, текст, виджет

Я делаю графический интерфейс с помощью Tkinter. Если коротко, то при нажатии кнопки в поле text должны появляться определённые значения, которые я хочу скопировать с помощью Ctrl+C. Чаще всего они копируются и вставляются куда надо. Но иногда после многочисленных таких действий (а иногда и просто при первом запуске программы) текст перестаёт копироваться. Бывает, если подшаманить, потыкаться в разные кнопки и текстовые виджеты, перезапустить программу или даже комп, то снова копируется, а иногда нет. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В tkinter Ctrl+C работает только в английской раскладке.

Comment: Спасибо вам, добрый человек, а то бы я так мучилась до конца жизни 